# localStorage with React behaving very erratically

Tags: reactjs, redux, local-storage, react-redux

I'm trying to display a profile component only when a user is logged in. I'm using localStorage to store if the user is logged in or not. Even when the boolean userLoggedIn is false, the component is rendered. I'm sure I'm making a really stupid mistake. Sorry in advance!

I'm using local state to decide if I want to render the component or not. When the component is loaded, I call:

```
 constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={showDropdown: false, userLoggedIn: false};
 }
```

Then, when the component mounts, I set the userLoggedIn state to either true or false.

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({userLoggedIn:            
    localStorage.getItem("userLoggedIn")});
}
```

When the user logs in, I set the localStorage boolean to true with:

```
localStorage.setItem('userLoggedIn', true);
```

This happens in an action creator. I use dev tools to check localstorage to verify if this works.

Then, in my component, I render this by calling a function:

```
{this.renderProfileButton()}
```

The function is:

```
renderProfileButton(){                  

    console.log("renderProfileButton:"
     +localStorage.getItem("userLoggedIn"));
    if(this.state.userLoggedIn){
            return(
                <ProfileContainer userLoggedIn=  {this.state.userLoggedIn}> 
                    <IconImage src="/static/profilepic.png" onClick=      
                      {()=>{this.toggleDropdown()}} />
                        <ProfileDropdown showDropdown=     
                          {this.state.showDropdown}>
                        <NavBarArrowDiv/>
                        <DropdownContent>
                            <LabelGrey onClick={()=>{this.logOutUser();
                                this.toggleDropdown();}}> Logout
                            </LabelGrey>
                        </DropdownContent>
                    </ProfileDropdown>
                </ProfileContainer>
            );
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason is, `localstorage` stores everything in `string` format**, even your `booloen` value will get saved as `'true'`, `'false'`, so either you need to check the `string` or use `JSON.parse` to convert it to `boolean` again, like this:

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({userLoggedIn:            
         JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userLoggedIn"))
    });
}
```

Or inside that `function` check the `string`, like this:

```
renderProfileButton(){                  

    console.log("renderProfileButton:" , localStorage.getItem("userLoggedIn"));
    if(this.state.userLoggedIn == 'true'){ //check 'true' here
    ....
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasted a couple of hours over two quotes. Should've read the docs.

Comment: glad, it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

You Item in `localStorage` is stored as a `String`, you need to use it like a string as

```
componentDidMount(){
    var userLoggedIn = (localStorage.getItem("userLoggedIn") === "true" ) ? true: false
    this.setState({userLoggedIn:            
    userLoggedIn});
}
```